# Octopus Deploy is not merging my transformation file when deploying application

Tags: web-config, octopus-deploy, web.config-transform, config-transformation, octopack

I have 3 transformation files in my mvc project called Web.Debug.config, Web.AWS QA.config, Web.Release.config. I have an environment called AWS QA.
[image]
I have checked both Configuration Variables and Configuration transforms in the Enable Features section of my build step, I have also added Web.AWS QA.config => Web.config to my Additional transforms section.

[image]

Yet, when i deploy to the AWS QA environment, i get what is in my normal web.config which is what i use when developing on my local machine, which does not include what i have in Web.AWS QA.config which is what i need. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you confirm that `Web.AWS QA.config` is actually being deployed?  If it isn't, you'll need to make sure that the file is marked as "Content" in Visual Studio.  Also, check the "Verbose" version of the task log -- it will tell you which files are being transformed.  In fact, you should see `Web.Release.config` being transformed in the log right now.

Comment: Can show post the relevant octopus log entries?

Comment: My guess would be that this relates to the space in the name. Did you ever work out what caused it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Add a powershell script to renam your files in octopus deploy using the Rename-Item command:

```
Rename-Item -Path "Web.AWS.QA.Config" -NewName "c:\yourpath\Web.config"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The file being referred to is an XML transform file which needs to be applied to the config file. It cannot be used as a replacement for the file.